# Get height of element from within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter, jquery-animate

I’m trying to animate an auto scroll on an `<ol>` tag within an `<iframe>` that calls a twitter feed.

[Demo](http://wildenmedia.com/twitter/withScroll/)

What I have now works, but it animates the height of the `<iframe>` which is wrong.

What I want is to have it animate the height of the `<ol>` that holds the feed lists. I noticed that the `<ol>` is the only one that has the total height of the feed.

I don’t know how, but somehow we need to get the height of this `<ol>` and animate the scroll on the `<iframe>` based on the height of the `<ol>`.

Here is my code:

```css
html{
 overflow:hidden !important;
}
body{
 background-color:#333;
}
#container{
 width:350px;
}
div.timeline div.stream{
 overflow:hidden !important;
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 overflow-y:hidden !important;
}
div.twtr-doc{
 margin-top: 37px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<script>
function scroll(speed) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document.getElementById("twitter-widget-0")).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function() {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
    });
}

speed = 1000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 1);
</script>

<div id="container">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/wildenmediainc" data-widget-id="539490745749475328" data-chrome="noscrollbar nofooter" width="350px;">Tweets by @wildenmediainc  </a>
 <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>

</body>
```

I’m trying to grab information from everywhere.

Comment: Is this code being executed by the HTML in the iframe or it's parent?

Comment: In other words, is the iframe executing the javascript, or is the page containing the iframe executing the javascript. If the iframe targets a different location than the parent, you're options become extremely limited (if any at all)

Comment: the Javascript is being executed by the the html page containing the iframe

Comment: But what I'm trying to do is to autoscroll the iframe to its total height 

the total height can be found in the ol height

Comment: OK Here is what I tried and It kinda fakes it 

min-height:4000px !important. Now it animates 4000px which is good but how can we make the min-height of the iframe equal to the height of the ol inside the iframe?